# AIDE: No access to variable C and Understanding Default Code?

Tags: java, android, aide-ide

I am pretty new to this but I have a couple of questions which may seem silly but I would really appreciate an answer. They are located right below the code block.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View p1) {
                    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview)).setText(getDiag(40));
                }
        });

        Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View p1) {
                    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview)).setText(getDiag(5));
                }
        });

    }

    public String getDiag(int n){
        String spaces = "";
        String finalstring = "";
        for(int i = 0; (i <= n); i++){  
            spaces += " ";  
            finalstring += spaces + "*" + "\n";  
            } 
        return finalstring;
        }}
```

So, to be clear about what my questions are:
1) What is this whole default method created by AIDE? Is it always required or can I also just write my usual java and run my methods without all the UI?

2) I have a problem somewhere with brackets, everything works fine until I added button c. I have no idea where exactly to place it, with the current code AIDE tells me it has no acess to the variable c. And where is the ")" on line 25 coming from?

Answer (score 1):

1. you can code it yourself, however you want
2. There is no access to Button c click because u made a small mistake:

Replace b into c at setOnClickListener:

```
    Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View p1) {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview)).setText(getDiag(5));
            }
    });
```

Should look like:

```
    Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View p1) {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview)).setText(getDiag(5));
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 1:
The default structure provided is the methods that give the lifecycle of an Android Application. They are defined to provide the flow for your App.
You can use service to write your java code without UI.

You can modify your button placement in the AndroidManifest.xml and check that you indeed have a button2.

Can you also provide a more detailed error.

I cannot see your line 25 but if you are talking about the onclickListener it is the signature for an anonymous class/interface implementation.

Comment: public void onClick(View p1) { ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview)).setText(getDiag(5)); } });, the parentheses at the end of this code. I'm not sure what it's closing. I think it may solve the variable c problem.